# DelegatingHandler SendAsync issue

Tags: c#, grpc

We are overriding the SendAsync method on the System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler in order to run some custom logic:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //logic block 1

    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    //logic block 2
}
```

Additionally, within the request calls we are making gRPC calls.

The issue that we are seeing is that sometimes when an error occurs, the code  in logic block 2 does not run and there is no clear reason for why it does not happen each time that we see an error.
We have only been seeing this issue on our IIS server and when we try to recreate this error locally, we are unable to reproduce it.

We have a feeling that the http message lifecycle is being cut short due to the unavavailablity or timeouts of gRPC.

Any ideas on the cause are appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you you use a try catch block within this handler and help the request to do whatever you want in catch